# node crashes when subscribe to /image_raw topic

Tags: ros, c++, node, nodelet, ros-noetic

I am trying to consolidate a few nodes into a single process using nodelets. I have a `ObjectDetectionNodelet` that has a subscriber that subscribes to the raw image data. Every time I run the subscriber node, it crashes the driver.

```
[camera_1_nodelet_manager-1] process has died [pid 15157, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_1_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/user/.ros/log/7d8a6240-bfde-11d3-9583-48b02d75c59c/camera_1_nodelet_manager-1.log].
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/7d8a6240-bfde-11d3-9583-48b02d75c59c/camera_1_nodelet_manager-1*.log
[camera_1/spinnaker_camera_nodelet_camera_1-2] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/7d8a6240-bfde-11d3-9583-48b02d75c59c/camera_1-spinnaker_camera_nodelet_camera_1-2*.log
[ObjectDetectionNodelet-3] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/7d8a6240-bfde-11d3-9583-48b02d75c59c/ObjectDetectionNodelet-3*.log
```

Can someone please evaluate by current setup and check launch files if I am doing any mistake in starting multiple nodelets? Any help is appreciated.

Following is my current setup:

- I am using Blackfly S cameras for my application and using the [spinnaker_camera_driver](https://github.com/ros-drivers/flir_camera_driver/tree/noetic-devel/spinnaker_camera_driver) to stream data and this publishes image data to a topic `/camera_1/image_raw` . Here is a [link](https://github.com/ros-drivers/flir_camera_driver/blob/noetic-devel/spinnaker_camera_driver/src/nodelet.cpp) to spinnaker nodelet that publishes raw data
- I have a separate package which contains code for object detection. My current launch file looks like the following where I setup a nodelet manager `camera_1_nodelet_manager` and start the `SpinnakerCameraNodelet` and `ObjectDetectionNodelet` in the same nodelet manager:

Main launch file -

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <launch>
>   <arg name="camera_name"               default="camera_1" />
>   <arg name="nodelet_manager_name"      default="$(arg camera_name)_nodelet_manager" />
> >       
> >       <!-- Nodelet manager-->
> >       <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="$(arg nodelet_manager_name)"  args="manager" output="screen"/>
>
>   <!-- Load spinnaker nodelet-->
>   <include file="$(find spinnaker_camera_driver)/launch/gige_camera.launch">
> >         <arg name="nodelet_manager_name"    value="$(arg nodelet_manager_name)" />
>     <arg name="camera_name"             value="$(arg camera_name)" />
> >       </include>
> >     
> >       <!-- Load object detection nodelet-->
> >       <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="ObjectDetectionNodelet" 
> >             args="load object_detection_nodelet/ObjectDetectionNodelet /$(arg nodelet_manager_name)">
>     <param name="camera_name"           value="$(arg camera_name)" />
>   </node>
> </launch>
> ```

And the included launch file from spinnaker camera driver is the following -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <arg name="camera_name"                     default="camera_1" />
  <arg name="calibrated"                      default="0" />
  <arg name="nodelet_manager_name"            default="camera_1_nodelet_manager" />

  <group ns="$(arg camera_name)">    
    <!-- Camera nodelet -->
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="spin_cam_nodelet" args="load spinnaker_camera_driver/SpinnakerCameraNodelet /$(arg nodelet_manager_name)" >
      <param name="frame_id"            value="$(arg camera_name)" />
    </node>
  </group>
</launch>
```

object_detection_nodelet.cpp is as follows:

```
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
#include <object_detection/object_detection_nodelet.h>

namespace object_detection_nodelet {

ObjectDetectionNodelet::ObjectDetectionNodelet() {}

void ObjectDetectionNodelet::onInit(void) {
  std::string cameraName;
  ros::NodeHandle& privateNh = getPrivateNodeHandle();

  privateNh.getParam("camera_name", cameraName);

  m_ObjectDetectionPtr_.reset(new ObjectDetection(cameraName, getNodeHandle()));
}
};  // namespace object_detection_nodelet

PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(object_detection_nodelet::ObjectDetectionNodelet, nodelet::Nodelet);
```

And the `object_detection.cpp` node which has the subscriber is as follows:

```
#include <object_detection/object_detection.h>

ObjectDetection::ObjectDetection(const std::string& cameraName, ros::NodeHandle& nh)
    : m_CameraName_(cameraName),
      tracker_(120) {

  image_sub = nh.subscribe(cameraName + "/image_raw", 10, &ObjectDetection::inputImageCallback_, this);
  image_pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Image>(cameraName + "/roi_image", 10);
}

void ObjectDetection::inputImageCallback_(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg) {
  cv::Mat inputImage = ImageConverter::convertToCvMat(msg);
  cv::Mat filteredImage;

  sensor_msgs::Image outputImageMsg = ImageConverter::convertToRosImage(filteredImage);
  image_pub.publish(outputImageMsg);
}
```

Comment: What actual error are you getting? You've provided a lot of information here, but not the actual error that you're trying to solve.

Comment: I have updated the post with the error message. It doesn't give any relevant info except that the process died

Comment: convertToRosImage() may not like a default-constructed cv::Mat. As Mike F suggests, the most efficient way to find the problem is to connect gdb to your running nodelet manager process.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that the problem is not with your posted code - but rather the driver itself.

The driver is likely implemented as a lazy publisher - this means that it does not interact with the hardware until a ROS subscriber connects and needs messages to be generated. I would suggest that you look at the logs from the driver itself to further debug this issue.

Comment: But if I launch the driver ros code by itself, then it publishes data to the topic. I can view it on `rqt_image_view`. In case of a lazy publisher that shouldn't work right?I am adding a [link](https://github.com/ros-drivers/flir_camera_driver/blob/noetic-devel/spinnaker_camera_driver/src/nodelet.cpp) to the actual spinnaker nodelet that publishes the raw image

Comment: Ok - that changes things quite a bit. Since everything is running inside the same nodelet manager your nodelet could actually be the thing crashing. I notice a bunch of pointers involved as well as an "ImageConverter" which we have no information about. Your error message has 3 log files - look in those for any output (is the format of the image incorrect, etc). If that doesn't give you any information, you likely have a segfault or similar issue which will involve connecting gdb to find out where your code is going wrong.